# Confirm Box OK/Cancel Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, confirm, html-datalist

I am just a Beginner

I was trying to define a function of Ok button click function of the alert box.
and as i read here in others users's Question about the same. i think i should you confirm box i tried to make the same function on OK/Cancel script below:-

```
(function(){
  $("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').blur(function(){
    var val=$("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').val();
    var obj=$("#KASHIPUR").find("option[value='"+val+"']");

    if(obj !=null && obj.length>0){
      return false;
    } else{
      confirm("TRUCK NUMBER IS NOT DEFINED\nPlease Enter A valid TRUCK NUMBER");
    }
  })
})();

{
  if (confirm("TRUCK NUMBER IS NOT DEFINED\nPlease Enter A valid TRUCK NUMBER") == true){
    (function(){
      if ($("label:contains('Vehical Type')").parent().next().find('input').val()==""){
        return false;
      } else
        ($("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').select())
    })
  } else {
    (function(){
      if ($("label:contains('Vehical Type')").parent().next().find('input').val()==""){
        return false;
      } else
        ($("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').select())
    })
  }
}
```

its not working. i want that if vehicle type is not blank then user can not do anything till i update the option value in the datalist which user want to put

after bookmarklet inputbox is as under:-

```
<input id="__input14-inner" value="" type="text" class="sapMInputBaseInner" maxlength="10" autocomplete="OFF" list="KASHIPUR" placeholder="TRUCK NUMBER" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 20px !important; background-color: white;">
```

bookmarklet

```
     $("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').attr({
        maxlength: "10",
        Autocomplete: "OFF",
        list: "KASHIPUR",
        Placeholder: "TRUCK NUMBER",
        style: "text-transform: uppercase"
        }).after('<Datalist ID=KASHIPUR></Datalist>');})();

var truck = new Array();
truck[0]='DL01GB2355';
truck[1]='HR38K1350';
truck[2]='HR38M4985';
truck[3]='HR46A9278';
truck[4]='HR51GA1620';
$(truck).ready( function() {
$(truck).each( function(index, item) {
    var option = $('<option value="'+item+'"></option>');
    $('#KASHIPUR').append(option);
});
});
```

Please help

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I'm not really sure that confirm is the correct thing to use in this case.  Confirm's are used when offering the user a yes/no option.  In your cause, the text appears to be directing the user to do an action on the page, which is more of an alert.  There really isn't a yes/no option there.  They need to do the action before continuing.  Allowing them to say "no" doesn't make sense.  Simply telling someone to do something falls more in line with the `alert()` method.

Comment: Sir I tested with alert also. problem is, if the value is not blank the alert box is showing again and again i want after click ok of the alert box, Input box should be selected where he was typing the input where i defined the blur function

Comment: Can you please include an example of the markup that this script is meant to run against?

Comment: Sure https://gist.githubusercontent.com/sachinsunny27/9fa535dee204d1612a968f420ce2f4ff/raw/b23926bd4cd9e17d5860105d76acf9d0de85ca94/TEST.JS

Comment: In the question, please.

Comment: There are many other things which i am doing there. i am just a upper person of users so tried to make their work easy with this bookmarklet.. as data once entered in the page cannot be reversed without the approvals of very high authorities of the company.. so learned little javascript in last 40 days over the net and tried to minimize the mistake of my users.. before 40 days i even don't knew what javascript is..

Comment: Right now I'm not asking for more javascript.  Your script is interacting with/checking elements on the page.  In order to do some review of how the script will interact when those elements, it would be beneficial to the readers if we could see the html that this script will interact with.

Comment: @SachinAgarwal - Do you have HTML that this JavaScript is interacting with? If so, please include that with your question.

Comment: @Chris <input id="__input14-inner" value="" type="text" class="sapMInputBaseInner" maxlength="10" autocomplete="OFF" list="KASHIPUR" placeholder="TRUCK NUMBER" style="text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 20px !important; background-color: yellow;">

Answer (score 0):

i tried with this one

```
(function(){
        $("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').blur(function(){
       var val=$("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').val();
        var obj=$("#KASHIPUR").find("option[value='"+val+"']");
                 if(obj !=null && obj.length>0 || $("label:contains('Vehical Type')").parent().next().find('input').val()=="")
                 return false;
                 else
                    alert("TRUCK NUMBER IS NOT DEFINED\nPlease Enter A valid TRUCK NUMBER");
$("label:contains('Truck No')").parent().next().find('input').focusin().select();})})
();
```

its working but blur function is on infinite loop in chrome

any idea how to solve it as i read here it is a chrome bug